# substrate Front-End Template connect localhost error

Tags: substrate

I am a newbie and experiencing same issue.

Using tutorial [https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup].

Successfully installed Node.js and Yarn - Launched the front-end-template (stated in the above link) in root directory, although I receive an error message in browser [Error Connecting to Substrate [object Event].

I have looked online for solution, but no success.

Would appreciate advice on where I'm going wrong also how to solve issue.

Answer (score 2):

Edit config file here:

```
./src/config/development.json
```

replace 127.0.0.1 with your IP address

`yarn start` and now system working.

Comment: this definitely work, I figured out the failed connection is made from the browser machine so 127.0.0.1 makes no sense at all

Answer (score 1):

Solved - I found that I can open multiple console windows (Visual Studio Code) from the dropdown 'default shell' - The 1st window ‘cd substrate-node-template/ ‘and run ‘cargo build –release’. In 2nd window ‘cd substrate-front-end template’ and run ‘start yarn’. I can connect to web page [localhost:8000/] and view information about the chain.
Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Hi @Tasszz44, I tried your solution but no luck. I am trying to load the front-end on my browser remotely. I am getting the same `Error Connecting to Substrate
[object Event]` error. Upon inspecting the browser window, I get the following - ```Provider.js:380 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
connect @ Provider.js:380 index.js:1 2020-10-11 20:16:56          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: Abnormal Closure ```. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated to rustup install nightly-2020-10-06 + rustup toolchain install nightly + rustup toolchain list  + rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2020-10-06-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Comment: theses update were done in substrate-node-template folder....

Comment: then run cargo build --release

Comment: then in same folder run - ./target/release/node-template --dev

Comment: In substrate-front-end-node run yarn start.... This worked for me..

Comment: ** [cargo build --release] = cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 build --release

Answer (score 0):

The front-end-template won't display anything unless a Substrate compatible chain node is running. In this case it should be the Substrate Node template running on the same machine where you are running the front-end.

You should first build your node-template with `cargo build --release` and then execute the binary `./target/release/node-template --dev`. This will start the Substrate node to which your front-end-template should connect.